# Is there life on the other 8 planets according to Hindu scripture?

Tags: scripture, astrology, life, navagraha

Is there life on the other 8 planets according to Hindu scripture?

I know there's life on the Sun (Suryaloka) and the Moon (Chandraloka).

Comment: other 8 ? of the nava-grahas, earth is not one (even though we call it planet). and 2 of the 9 are not physical places. 7 days of the week refer to 7 of the 9 'solid' bodies - rahu & ketu are nodes.

Comment: Grahas are not planets which we know. "Grah" literally means "seize off", In short, graha is the one which affects you. Out of them two are, Chaya Grahas, Rahu and Ketu and Surya and Chandra are also Grahas.

Comment: @ram Yes, I meant those 7 physical planets.

Answer (score 3):

Jiva's goes to archirathi marga through sun (only noble souls or moksha yogis)
Other Jivas goes to Chandra loka (enjoy good deeds and come back to earth)
Bad jivas goes to Yama loka

All this are non physical entities and their names, so if scripture says surya lokha means its not the physical sun..

Spirtual World is always hidden not explicitly seen.

When jiva leaves body in sad taught and bad taught. the suffering is explicable need to suffer till it expatiate the bad energy from the taught.

When jiva leaves body in good taught they enjoy the happiness till they spend the energy and get back to earth..

Comment: The question is existence of life on other planets (not lokas, grahas) like Mercury, Venus, Jupiter etc., So,, the answer should give the existence or non existence of life on other planets. By the way, Shukracharya is given the status of a graha and he is the same as Shukra graha (Venus).

Comment: if you see the physical grahas they jada but hindu shukra is not physical its more than physical it had got jiva..from spritual prespective all nine planet is devatha.. with life force, they themselves are life. but if consider  scientifically they deny sun is not having life.. so that is the state of science.. since its hindu group there is nothing science discussed.. my answer is every planet is have life itself..